# Setting xticklabels, x axis formatting in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I would like to format my x axis with the legend values at the mid point of each bar whilst retaining the gender group identification. I'd like lower the gender groups to sit below the other xticklabels for clarity.

To this point, I've added xticks but actually labeling them correctly and neatly is proving trickier.

[image]

```
from itertools import chain, cycle
import logging
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
matplotlib.style.use("ggplot")


m = {"Males" :  {"Yes": 2, "No": 8}}
w = {"Females": {"Yes": 3, "No": 7}}
data = {**m, **w}
df = DataFrame(data)
# relative freq table
df_ft = (df / df.sum() * 100).T

ax = plt.subplot(111)
df_ft.plot(ax=ax, kind="bar", ylim=(0, 90),
           title="Would you prefer to work at home? (10 males, 10 females)",
           rot=0)
plt.ylabel("Relative Frequency (%)")


midp = 0.125  # standard bar width/2
t_l = ax.get_xticks().tolist()
ticks = list(chain.from_iterable((t - midp, t + midp) for t in t_l))
ax.set_xticks(t_l + ticks)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might be what you're looking for.

```
from itertools import chain
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import DataFrame
matplotlib.style.use("ggplot")


df = DataFrame({'Males': {'Yes': 2, 'No': 8}, 'Females': {'Yes': 3, 'No': 7}})

df_ft = (df / df.sum() * 100).T

ax = plt.subplot(111)
df_ft.plot(ax=ax, kind="bar", ylim=(0, 90),
           title="Would you prefer to work at home? (10 males, 10 females)",
           rot=0)
plt.ylabel("Relative Frequency (%)")


midp = 0.125  # standard bar width/2
t_l = ax.get_xticks().tolist()
ticks = list(chain.from_iterable((t - midp, t + midp) for t in t_l))
ax.set_xticks(t_l + ticks)

labels = [l for l in ax.get_xticklabels()]
for i,l in enumerate(labels[len(df_ft):]):
    l.set_text(df_ft.columns[i % len(df_ft.columns)])
for i,l in enumerate(labels[:len(df_ft)]):
    l.set_text("\n"+l.get_text())

ax.set_xticklabels(labels)

plt.savefig(__file__+".png")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Altair would do a great job here.

```
from altair import *
from pandas import DataFrame


df = DataFrame({'Males': {'Yes': 2, 'No': 8}, 'Females': {'Yes': 3, 'No': 7}})
df = df.stack().reset_index()
df.columns=['response','gender','count']
```

#### Vis #1

```
Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(x='gender',y='count',color='response').configure_cell(width=200, height=200)
```

[image]

#### Vis 2

```
Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(x=X('response', axis=False),
                            y=Y('count', axis=Axis(grid=False)),
                            color='response',
                            column=Column('gender', axis=Axis(axisWidth=1.0, offset=-8.0, orient='bottom'),scale=Scale(padding=30.0))).configure_cell(width=200, height=200).configure_facet_cell(strokeWidth=0)
```

[image]